# How to obtain the HTML DOM element of a Google Maps marker?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-maps

Given a GMarker JS variable, how do I obtain the HTML DOM element that represents it? I need this so I can insert a `<div>` of my own into the map with the correct z-index.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065485/get-dom-element-of-a-marker-in-google-maps-api-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Google Maps API doesn't provide a method to return a marker's DOM element.

Do you just want to create your own custom marker?  If so, you can create a marker class which extends GOverlay.  [MarkerLight](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/manymarkers/markerlight.js) is a great example of how to accomplish this (and here is the [example page](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/manymarkers/randommarkers.html)).

If all you need is a custom icon, [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Custom_Icons) is how to do that.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry to post on such an old question, but I've just come across this myself. The solution I used in Google Maps APIv3 was to copy the "Custom Marker" from [the Google Maps samples](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/overlayview/custommarker.html) and add a simple method `getDOMElement`, which returns the `div` generated in the Marker's construction.

```
CustomMarker.prototype.getDOMElement = function() {
  return this.div_;
}
```

You can then use `marker.getDOMElement().style` to dynamically change the styling of your marker, and the `img` child element of `marker.getDOMElement()` is the icon used, so you can change that dynamically too.

Answer (score 1):

This a simpler CustomMarker I'm using. Just provide a DOM element to it and it will be used as marker!

```
// based on http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/overlayview/custommarker.html

function CustomMarker(options) {
  this.options = options;
  this.element = options.element;
  this.map = options.map;
  this.position = options.position;
  this.positionFunction = options.positionFunction || function () {
    var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.position);
    if (point) {
      this.element.style.position = 'absolute';
      this.element.style.left = (point.x - jQuery(this.element).width()/2) + 'px';
      this.element.style.top = (point.y - jQuery(this.element).height()) + 'px';
      this.element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    }
  };

  this.setMap(this.map);
}

CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
  if (!this.div_)
    this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.element);
  this.positionFunction();
};
CustomMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {
  return this.position;
};
CustomMarker.prototype.setVisible = function(bool) {
  jQuery(this.element).toggle(bool);
};
```

~