# Get DOM Element of a marker in Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom

I'm trying to find a way to get the DOM element of a marker. It seems that Google uses different elements for showing a marker and one of handling the event.

I've figured out 2 things so far. 
There's a generated variable called `fb` that holds the DOM element on a marker object, but I think the next time Google updates the API, it will be named something different. So no go.

Second, if one attach a click event to a marker the API send the event DOM element as arguments to what ever function you have specified. While looking through it in Firebug I can't find any relations between the two.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to manipulate the DOM element() and feed it more information then just a 'div' element with a background.

I've done this in version 2 using a name property(undocumented) that generates an id on the div element.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: When you say "feed it" what do you mean exactly?  HTML for an InfoWindow or Overlay?

Comment: Replace the icon with a html element that holds an new icon with text and a link on it.

Comment: Also it would be fantastic to know why Google never implemented (and documented) a native method to retrieve this. Or just have a HTML property on the Marker object that creates an wrapper of given size. And the you can mess around with it how ever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a really really bad workaround. One can use the title attribute to pass a id property.

```
fixMarkerId = function () {
                $('div[title^="mtg_"]').each(function (index, elem) {
                    el = $(elem);
                    el.attr('id', el.attr('title'));
                    el.removeAttr('title');
                });
            },
            tryAgainFixMarkerId = function () {
                if ($('div[title^="mtg_"]').length) {
                    fixMarkerId();
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        tryAgainFixMarkerId();
                    }, 100);
                };
            }

if ($('div[title^="mtg_"]').length) {
                fixMarkerId();
            } else {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    tryAgainFixMarkerId();
                }, 100);
            };
```

I would strongly not recommend this solution for any production environment. But for now I use it so that I can keep developing. But still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 19):

I've found this method to be useful, although it might not be suitable for all environments.
When setting the marker image, add a unique anchor to the URL. 
For example:

```
// Create the icon
var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    "data/ui/marker.png",
    new google.maps.Size(64, 64),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(48, 32)
);

// Determine a unique id somehow, perhaps from your data
var markerId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
icon.url += "#" + markerId;

// Set up options for the marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    optimized: false,
    icon: icon,
    id: markerId,
    uniqueSrc: icon.url
});
```

Now you have a unique selector i.e.:

```
$("img[src='data/ui/marker.png#619299']")
```

or if you have the marker:

```
$("img[src='" + marker.uniqueSrc + "']")
```

Comment: awsm. 6 years later and this technique still works for me!

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the DOM element too in order to implement a custom tooltip.
After a while digging into google overlays, custom libraries and so on,  i've ended up with the following solution based on fredrik's title approach (using jQuery) :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

    if (!this.hovercardInitialized) {

        var markerInDOM = $('div[title="' + this.title + '"]').get(0);

        // do whatever you want with the DOM element

        this.hovercardInitialized = true;
    }

});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

1. Customize overlays (by implements onAdd, draw, remove) while drag it has some issues.
2. Maybe you can get the marker dom element by the class name `gmnoprint` and the index it has been appended in.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked that google maps marker click event has a MosueEvent property in it and the target of the mouse event is the dom element of the marker.

It worked for me until i found out that the property name has changed from tb to rb. I did not know why and I could not find an explaination for that in the google maps api docs but I have created a work around.

I check the click event object properties for the one which is an instance of MouseEvent and I use its target as the marker dom element.

```
marker.addListener('click', (e) => {

      let markerElement;

   // with underscore
    _.toArray(markerClickEvent).some(item => {
        if (item instanceof MouseEvent) {
            markerElement = item.target;
            return true;
        }
    });
  // or maybe with for loop
for (let key in markerClickEvent) {
        if (markerClickEvent.hasOwnProperty(key) && markerClickEvent[key] instanceof MouseEvent) {
            markerElement = markerClickEvent[key].target;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```