# Get the DOM element associated with a Leaflet class

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there a way to get the corresponding DOM element of a [Marker](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker) or [Layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#ilayer) with Leaflet, [like it is with Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233034/how-to-obtain-the-html-dom-element-of-a-google-maps-marker)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the internal `._container` property on most Leaflet objects, like layers and markers. Note that it's internal for a reason - if you use Canvas mode or Leaflet decides to change its internal API, your code will break.

Comment: It seems odd that vector layers (now) support the `className` option for use with the SVG renderer but not a way to change the class list after instantiation.

Answer (score 5):

`getContainer()` is a more formal way to get at the DOM element, but is only available on the [Map](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getcontainer), [TileLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-getcontainer), and [Controls](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-getcontainer) classes.

Comment: And `getElement()` appears to work for the [Marker](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker) class.