# Can I get leaflet map object through dom getElementByID()?

Tags: angular, dom, leaflet, getelementbyid

I'm using Angular 7 and I need to set a marker on map which is in entirely different component, is it possible to access the leaflet object throught DOM and make changes to it?
I don't want to make any major changes to the existing map component. Thanks!

Comment: I already searched many times for this but I didn't found a solution. So I suggest you to store the map object somewhere global, where you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to keep the MapInstance in the service and create map methods service.

This way at any point in the application you have access to the map object and call any number of methods using map methods service. It will keep the map object and map methods loosely coupled.

Comment: If I understand your post correct, then you are not answering the question. He wants to get the Leaflet Map-Object from the DOM Element and not like you say the DOM Element from the Map-Object over `getContainer()`

Comment: Is not possible to take the map instance by DOM api? because in our project we have one global map object and work on it. This what I recommended him though there might be other way to do it. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278282/get-the-dom-element-associated-with-a-leaflet-class). Does it make sense?